# Stored procedure: delete rows from multiple tables with output for every row

Tags: stored-procedures, output, azure-sql-database, delete-row, multiple-tables

I want to delete rows from 3 related tables in a stored procedure entering the ID of Table1 (t1ID).

```
Table1       Table2       Table3
-------      -------      -------
t1ID         t2ID         t3ID
name         t1ID         t2ID
             blobpath1    blobpath2
```

I need to get the values of blobpath1 and blobpath2 of every deleted row as output from the procedure, because I have to delete blob storage outside of the database.

Usually I would do:

```
Delete From [dbo].[Table3]  Where t2ID IN
(Select t2ID FROM [dbo].[Table2] Where [t1ID]= @t1ID)
Delete From [dbo].[Table2] Where [t1ID]= @t1ID
Delete From [dbo].[Table1] Where [t1ID]= @t1ID
```

How can I output the blobpaths?

Comment: Which database are you using (`SQL Server`, `Oracle`, etc)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it fairly simply using the [`OUTPUT`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx) clause;

```sql
BEGIN TRANSACTION;

DECLARE @blobpaths TABLE ( blobpath VARCHAR(32) );

DELETE t3 OUTPUT deleted.blobpath2 INTO @blobpaths
FROM table3 t3 
JOIN table2 t2 ON t2.t2id = t3.t2id
JOIN table1 t1 ON t1.t1id = t2.t1id 
WHERE t1.t1id = @t1ID;

DELETE t2 OUTPUT deleted.blobpath1 INTO @blobpaths
FROM table2 t2 
JOIN table1 t1 ON t1.t1id = t2.t1id
WHERE t1.t1id = @t1ID;

DELETE FROM table1 WHERE t1id = @t1ID;

SELECT blobpath FROM @blobpaths;

COMMIT TRANSACTION;
```

[An SQLfiddle to test with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/0495c/10).

Comment: I don't get the where condition on the first delete. shouldn't it be Where t1.t1id= @t1ID or am I missing something?
Does this version have a better performance, because there aren't so many select queries?

Comment: @purbsel Yes, the `where` should be whatever you want to select on, I just kept the same as I had in the sample. `Where t1.t1id= @t1ID` seems correct in your case. As to performance, I suspect it will be better than creating /inserting into temp tables, but as always, if performance is essential, the best way to find out is always by testing with a realistic dataset.

Comment: Thanks for your help. there is only one mistake left: the order of the delete statements. t3 has to be the first table to delete, because of the foreign key relationships. So its: delete t3, delete t2, delete t1. And I think Table deleted1 is not needed anymore.

Comment: @purbsel Updated with the deletes in the desired order.

Comment: great, so I could double check with my solution :-), I have some joins less, but that's not important, both work!

Answer (score 1):

You could create a temporary table to store the `blobpath1` and `blobpath2` values and output this at the end:

```
-- Create a temporary table to hold results
CREATE TABLE #tmpResults
(  blobpath  VARCHAR(100)  )

-- Get results from Table2
INSERT INTO #tmpResults (blobpath)
  SELECT  blobpath1
    FROM  Table2
    WHERE t1ID = @t1ID

-- Get results from Table3
INSERT INTO #tmpResults (blobpath)
  SELECT  t3.blobpath2
    FROM  Table3 t3
      INNER JOIN Table2 t2 ON t2.t2ID = t3.t2ID
    WHERE  t2.t1ID = @t1ID

-- Do your deletes as per your own code


-- Output temporary table
SELECT  blobpath
  FROM  #tmpResults

-- Tidy up
DELETE #tmpResults
```

Note that I am unsure which RDBMS you are using so I have assumed SQL Server.  You may need to alter the temporary table syntax if it is another system.  I have also assumed your `blobpath` columns are `VARCHAR(100)` - you will need to change this to the appropriate type and size.

Upon executing your stored procedure you will receive a table output with a single column (`blobpath`) containing all of the values from `blobpath1` and `blobpath2` that you deleted.

Comment: this solution is also working perfect, but I chose the other one, because it's less code. Thank you for your fast support!